# reorder list of ggplots using do.call and gridExtra

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have a list of ggplots that I've created as `gglist`that contain `ggplot1`, `ggplot2` and `ggplot3`. I want to arrange them using `grid.arrange()` as such:

```
do.call(grid.arrange,gglist)
```

However, I want to reorder so that they appear in the sequence `ggplot3`, `ggplot1`an `ggplot2`. How do I do that with the `do.call` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to reorder how the graphs stored in gglist come in by using `[c(your order)]`

In this case:

```
do.call(grid.arrange, gglist[c(3,1,2)])
```

If you're specifying the order of the graphs, you do not even have to use `do.call` and just use the `grid.arrange` function normally like:

```
grid.arrange(ggplot3, ggplot1, ggplot2)
```

Comment: I wanted to use `do.call` for when I have a list of 10 grobs and not having to type it all out. Thank you for your very simple solution :)

Comment: No need for do.call, see grobs argument